seeking with CSS Animation
If anyone can help me, I'm encountering issues with the animation. I want to keep the same animation style for 'utilisation ILLIMITÉE', but when 'utilisation ILLIMITÉE' disappears, 'sans contact' takes its place in the same position and with the same animation, and so on for the other texts. Then, we loop back to the same thing.  Using only HTML and CSS. Can anyone help?


@keyframes coolAnimation {
    0%, 100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

#textContainer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden; /* Cacher tout débordement */
}

.coolText {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    animation: coolAnimation 6s ease-in-out infinite;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
}

.coolText:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s; }
.coolText:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 3s; }
.coolText:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 6s; }
.coolText:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 9s; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Cool Text Animation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="textContainer">
            <h3 class="coolText"> UTULISATION <br>ILLIMITEÉ </h3>
            <h3 class="coolText"> SANS <br>CONTACT </h3>
            <h3 class="coolText">SANS <br>ABONNEMENT</h3>
            <h3 class="coolText">ECO- <br> RESPONSABLE</h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>




I don't understand when you say sans contact displays correctly the first time, but that all the texts should display in the same place, sans contact does not display in the same place as utlisation illimitee.

Hi, Haworth thanks for your response.
That's exactly the problem. I want to keep the same animation style for 'utilisation ILLIMITÉE', but when 'unlimited usage' disappears, 'sans contact' takes its place in the same position and with the same animation, and so on for the other texts. Then, we loop back to the same thing.

The timing needs correction.
Each piece of text is to go up and down in 3 seconds, then it needs to stay down and out of sight while 3 other texts have a go.
This means that its total animation time is 12 seconds, 9 of which it is to be totally out of sight.
So, its in-sight animation lasts for 25% of the total 12seconds 0 and half way thro' that it reaches full opacity, then goes back down to 0 opacity by 25%.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Cool Text Animation</title>
  <style>
    @keyframes coolAnimation {
      0%,
      25% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(100%);
      }
      12.5% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
      }
    }
    
    #textContainer {
      position: relative;
      roverflow: hidden;
      /* Cacher tout débordement */
    }
    
    .coolText {
      color: #000000;
      font-family: 'Myriad Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      font-size: 40px;
      animation: coolAnimation 12s ease-in-out infinite;
      position: relative;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(100%);
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    .coolText:nth-child(1) {
      animation-delay: 0s;
    }
    
    .coolText:nth-child(2) {
      animation-delay: 3s;
    }
    
    .coolText:nth-child(3) {
      animation-delay: 6s;
    }
    
    .coolText:nth-child(4) {
      animation-delay: 9s;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="textContainer">
    <h3 class="coolText"> UTULISATION <br>ILLIMITEÉ </h3>
    <h3 class="coolText"> SANS <br>CONTACT </h3>
    <h3 class="coolText">SANS <br>ABONNEMENT</h3>
    <h3 class="coolText">ECO- <br> RESPONSABLE</h3>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Haworth, I'm sorry. I encountered another issue when using position: absolute. The text moves along with the overflow, which is not intended. :/

Sorry I don't understand what you mean. I am seeing no overflow.

In my main code, because this was an excerpt from my full code.

I don't think we can debug code we can't see! This sounds like a new question.

Anyway, thank you. Your response was very helpful. So now, I need to debug the second problem. If I can't solve it, I will post a new question. Thank you again.
